# Как настроить выпадающее меню?

Tags: css

Подскажите, как сделать, чтобы при наведении на пункт меню, выпадающее меню выезжало снизу главного пункта меню?
А сейчас, при наведении на 1й пункт меню, вложенное меню выезжает над первым пунктом. z-index у главного меню больше, чем у вложенного, почему тогда не перекрывается вложенное меню?
https://jsfiddle.net/1a6bL5hy/

```css
.menu{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    outline: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 50;
}
.menu ul{
    padding-top: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    outline: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: .5s;
    overflow: hidden;
}

li:hover{
  background: #f8f6f7;
}
li:hover a{
    color: #d24a43;
  }
li:hover>ul{
  opacity: 1;
  left: calc(100% + 1px);
}

h2,li{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <h2>item1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <h2>inner2</h2>
        <ul>
          <li>inner3</li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>inner2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @word то, что вопрос сложный - не повод постить его несколько раз подряд.

Answer (score 2):

Вот возможное решение -  [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/y7de767d/)

```css
.menu{
    ;
    top: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    outline: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 50;
} 
.menu > li {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
}
.menu > li h2,
.menu > li span {
  position: relative;
  z-index:2;
}
.menu li:before {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 1;
  background: #fff;
}
.menu > li ul {
    padding-top: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    outline: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: .5s;
}
li{
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: #fff;
}
  li.active a, li:hover a{
          color: #d24a43;
    }
li.active > ul, li:hover >ul{
  opacity: 1;
  left: calc(100% + 1px);
}

h2,li{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <h2>item1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li><h2>iinner1</h2>
        <ul><li><h2>iinner3</h2><span>i</span></li></ul>
      </li>
      <li><h2>iinner2</h2></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Nikita и Yuriy Chaban, ваше решение вообще не соответствует вопросу

Comment: подскажите пожалуйста, как это сделать?

Comment: @word, что именно подсказать?

Comment: в вашем решении дочерний пункт выезжает не так, как в моём примере. Нужно чтобы дочерний элемент выезжал напротив родителя

Comment: @word, сейчас попробую исправить

Comment: @word я обновил свой ответ, можете проверить так ли как вам нужно. Но я бы советовал при hover делать не display: block; в css а с помощью js fadeIn("slow"); либо другую плавную анимацию

Comment: сейчас ваше решение по вашему соответствует моему вопросу?

Comment: аргументируйте подробнее ваш вопрос, на картинке лутше, чтоб точно знать какой должен быть результат, ибо я ваc не могу понять правильно

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/1a6bL5hy/1/ в этом примере видно, как должны выезжать дочерние элементы, т.е. при наведении на родительский пункт меню, дочерний элемент должен выезжать справа, заметьте что не снизу должен выезжать, а справа, и родительский элемент должен перекрывать дочерний, т.е. чтобы небыло видно анимацию выезжания дочернего элемента. По идее из первого моего примера это было понятно

Comment: @word, ага, кажется я понял, сейчас исправлю свой ответ

Comment: @word, я обновил свой ответ, проверте пожалуйсста

Comment: отлично, благодарю

Comment: @word, рад был помочь

Comment: только заметил, ваше решение работает, но теперь не видно ховер эффект при наведении на пункт меню.  т.е. before перекрывает ховер-эффект. Можно ли как-то это исправить?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62481/discussion-between-word-and-yuriy-chaban).

Answer (score 0):

Я попробовал, немного похоже на то, что ты просил. Единственная проблема, нельзя на жать на item2 из-за того, что item3 вылетает.

```css
.menu{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: 300px;
    outline: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 50;
}
.menu ul{
    padding-top: 0px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 55px;
    left: 0;
    width: 300px;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    outline: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: .5s;
}
li{
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0px 0;
  background: #fff;
}
li:hover{
    a{
      color: #d24a43;
    }
}
li:hover>ul{
  opacity: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
h2,li{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <h2>item1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>inner1
        <ul><li>inner3</li></ul>
      </li>
      <li>inner2</li>
      <li>inner3</li>
      <li>inner4</li>
      <li>inner5</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: ваше решение не соответствует вопросу

Comment: @word Я неправильно понял вопрос из-за этой строчки `Как сделать, чтобы вложенные пункты меню выезжали снизу пункта-родителя?`