# Выпадающее меню, вложенность

Tags: css

В приведённом примере вложенный пункты меню выезжают над первым пунктом меню.
Как сделать, чтобы вложенные пункты меню выезжали снизу пункта-родителя?
т.е. при наведении на родительский пункт меню, дочерний элемент должен выезжать справа от родителя, и при анимации, дочернего элемента не должно быть видно за родительским элементом

https://jsfiddle.net/1a6bL5hy/1/

```css
.menu{
    position: relative;
    top: 10px;
    width: 30%;
    outline: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    background: #fff;
    z-index: 50;
}
.menu ul{
    padding-top: 5px;
    opacity: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    background: #fff;
    outline: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
    z-index: 0;
    transition: .5s;
}
li{
  padding: 20px 0;
  background: #fff;
}
li:hover{
    a{
      color: #d24a43;
    }
}
li:hover>ul{
  opacity: 1;
  left: 100%;
}
h2,li{
  font-size: 16px;
  color: #000;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu">
  <li>
    <h2>item1</h2>
    <ul>
      <li>inner1
        <ul><li>inner3</li></ul>
      </li>
      <li>inner2</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что не стоит повторять один и тот же вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/693479/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8E    Раз не ответили, значит, вопрос никому не интересен.